# Wake up a laptop that which has Lubuntu server installed

Tags: server, lubuntu, samsung, lid

My samsung NC10 laptop has Lubuntu server installed, after its lid is colsed, I cant wake it up by anyway.

That time, I cant control it over ssh, cant use Magic SysRq, or even cant shutdown by long press the power button!

Who can help me?

Comment: Please provide your release details, Lubuntu is a desktop release, a different desktop to standard Ubuntu desktop (LXDE or LXQt depending on release) and is not a server release.

Comment: Why is "#tag SLOVED" in the title? If this was solved, where is the answer?

Comment: I sloved by myself: It can boot later
.the solution is : Wait.